# Facebook Custom Post

Tags: facebook

I have a question about my wall post. I want to share this one post to this one friend, because I only want her to read it. Will her friends see that particular post?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the privacy setting feature, if you're talking about a post that is created by an application. You may refer to this link instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the risk by sending her a private message instead. That way the privacy is guaranteed in the thread specifically.